# Why doesn't Android Studio detect my phone?

Tags: android, flutter

Why doesn't Android Studio detect my device?

What I tried:
-I enabled developer options & USB Debugging on my Android phone
-I checked that the USB driver for my phone is installed & updated
-I checked that the USB option is set to "File transfer / Android Auto"
-I uninstalled Android Studio & reinstalled it.
-My phone can be found when running "Troubleshoot Device Connecions", but it says "Unable to locate ADB"
-I have checked that I have a SDK selected

What can I do?
Android Studio doesn't recognize my phone... It worked in the past with the same computer & the same phone.

Comment: Have you tried killing the adb daemon on the computer?

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem before

In my case, there were two different versions of ADB on my computer.
(which I had installed manually not from android SDK)

after uninstalling the old version and replacing android studio's own adb the problem resolved

Comment: I have only installed it with Android Studio platform tools, so this doesn't work for me unfortunately...

Comment: does your command prompt recognize ADB ?
I mean does your ADB path has been settled on the system environment?